# Placing an 'Are you Sure' alert before deleting an account

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app using Firebase database.  I also have a function connected to a button to delete their firebase account but i need to place some sort of alert to ask the user 'Are you sure?'.

**Delete function:**

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let firebase = Database.database().reference()

    // ... removes auth account

    user?.delete(completion: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Auth Deleted")
        }
    })


    // ... removes account from database

    firebase.child("Users/Riders").child((user?.uid)!).removeValue { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            print("Database acct deleted!")
        }
    }

    self.logOutAction(self)
```

I now need to create an alert that when the user presses the Delete button, an alert pops up with 2 options Yes or No.  If they press yes, the 'Delete' function is activated and if they press no, it cancels the action.

I know how to create an alert, I just don't know how to implement the function 'Delete' when user presses "yes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before running this deletion function, you can look at [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) to accomplish this. You can set a handler for the confirmation action that actually calls through to your deletion function. Make sure you run it from the main thread.

For example, the function that you wire up to the delete button could look like this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Account", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this account?", preferredStyle: .alert)

let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) in
    print("Call the deletion function here")
    self.processDelete()
})
alert.addAction(deleteAction)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I understand how to create an alert but what i am not sure of is how to implement the function into the action

Comment: I updated the answer to show an example of what a function handling the delete button could look like. You basically want to wire your button action to a "confirmDelete" function, and inside that function, present the alert. Once that has been presented, it can call through to a "processDelete" function that actually executes the deletion, containing the code you have in your original post.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

First create your function

```
@objc func Delete() {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let firebase = Database.database().reference()

    // ... removes auth account

    user?.delete(completion: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Auth Deleted")
        }
    })


    // ... removes account from database

    firebase.child("Users/Riders").child((user?.uid)!).removeValue { (error,        ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            print("Database acct deleted!")
        }
    }

    self.logOutAction(self)
}
```

Then call it in an alert like this

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "Are you sure    you want to permanently delete your account?", preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in self.Delete()}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

self.present(alert, animated: true)
```